# What is a "driving wheel"?

Tags: meaning

The folk song "[In the Pines](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2MkfTYPmLlA)" tells that the head of the dead husband was found "in a driving wheel". Some versions of the song mention a train, but I cannot imagine how a head could be found in a train's [driving wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driving_wheel).

What is a driving wheel in this context? And if it is on a train, [as some variants suggest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_the_Pines), how can a head be found "in it"?

Comment: The relevant [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_the_Pines) says *While early renditions which mention the head in the ["**driver's wheel**"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driving_wheel) make clear that the decapitation was caused by the train, some later versions would omit the reference to the train and reattribute the cause.* And they helpfully provide a hotlink to that highlighted term, explaining what a ***Driving wheel*** means. I'm a bit inclined to think you should have gone to Wikipedia first, and that this question is bordering on General Reference.

Comment: In your link to the Wikipedia page on a train's driving wheel, you have your answer: Many versions of the American folk song "In the Pines" performed by artists such as Leadbelly and Nirvana (On MTV Unplugged In New York) reference a decapitated man's head found in a driving wheel. Is there something about that gruesome detail you are not understanding?

Comment: @FumbleFingers But user what _did_ go to Wikipedia first, as they _themselves_ link to both articles.

Comment: I'm not sure you all managed to read my question to the end. A driving wheel has no space inside it that could hold a human head. Please explain to me how a human head can be found in a driving wheel.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about how a head could be caught in an apparently closed driving wheel - not about English language usage.

Comment: There's considerable discussion of the development of this folk song, its relation to other similar songs (song cluster), and the relevance of the driving wheel at Mudcat: http://mudcat.org/thread.cfm?threadid=38433

Comment: @MetaEd Thank you, that answers my question. The phrase was "caught in the wheel", and the "caught" was corrupted to "found". If you make that an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a driving wheel, from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driving_wheel).

[image: Steam locomotive driving wheel]
Sean Lamb, Wikimedia Commons

That image gives no indication of size, but since some such wheels can be huge, there may well be enough space between the spokes for a head to get wedged there.

Comment: I haven't just *attempted* an answer. This image shows that a head may found caught in a wheel. Driving wheels are not solid: they're often spoked.

Comment: About 35 years ago a fellow plunged onto the track and was killed by a train at my local station.

His head and hands were found nearly 10 miles along at the next stop. Since there were no bloodstains and trains don't need bumpers (fenders) the wheels - much as Andrew's - were as suspect as any other part of the mechanism.